how to build gnutls for android
I'm trying to read a library to use gnutls on Android. I downloaded the library from the link below.
https://www.gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/gnutls/v3.7/
To build for Android, I moved to the gnutls directory in the terminal and executed the command below.
./configure --host=aarch64-linux-android \ 
            --prefix=/my_path/gnutls/build \
            --disable-guile --disable-doc --disable-tests \
            --with-included-libtasn1 --with-included-unistring --with-nettle-mini \
            --with-included-libgmp=/my_path/gmp

It seems to have been executed normally, so now run make.
make

I get an error:
../../../../lib/accelerated/aarch64/elf/sha1-armv8.s:50:1: error: unknown directive
.hidden _gnutls_arm_cpuid_s
^
../../../../lib/accelerated/aarch64/elf/sha1-armv8.s:52:1: error: unknown directive
.type sha1_block_data_order,%function
^
../../../../lib/accelerated/aarch64/elf/sha1-armv8.s:1120:1: error: unknown directive
.size sha1_block_data_order,.-sha1_block_data_order
^
../../../../lib/accelerated/aarch64/elf/sha1-armv8.s:1121:1: error: unknown directive
.type sha1_block_armv8,%function
^
../../../../lib/accelerated/aarch64/elf/sha1-armv8.s:1250:1: error: unknown directive
.size sha1_block_armv8,.-sha1_block_armv8
^
../../../../lib/accelerated/aarch64/elf/sha1-armv8.s:1266:19: error: unexpected token in '.section' directive
.section .note.GNU-stack,"",%progbits
                  ^
make[5]: *** [elf/sha1-armv8.lo] Error 1
make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2


Thanks for your help.
